# Increase flag weight for successful close votes

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, flag-weight

For 3000+ rep users with the vote-to-close privilege, a duplicate flag is automatically turned into a duplicate vote-to-close. This makes perfect sense. However, as introducing the Marshal badge implicitly turned reaching a flag weight of 749 into an officially desirable goal ("Gold Badges are rare. You’ll have to actively work toward these. They’re something of an accomplishment!", cf. any badge site), this makes it even harder for users to reach that flag weight (≙[636 successful flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97890/how-many-flags-to-reach-750-flag-weight)).

It might not be so much of an issue at a huge site like SO, but on a smaller site like tex.sx it's virtually impossible to reach that flag weight this way. Tex.sx is pretty disciplined and I'd say most flags are dupe flags, the ones mentioned at [Increasing Flag Weight when you have Voting Privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96359/increasing-flag-weight-when-you-have-voting-privileges) aren't too frequent.

My proposal,  as a basis for discussion, is:

**Increase a user's flag weight for a vote-to-close that contributed to the closing of a question as if it were a flag marked "helpful".**

Comment: IMO, that would just encourage pile-on voting for free (and risk-free, since close votes can't be declined) flag weight.

Comment: You don't have enough bad first answers / late answers that are very low quality or not an answer there? Wow, that's a great problem to have. There is an endless supply at SO.

Comment: @agf: Hold on... migrating some now.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, this is a bad idea indeed. lunbok has a point:

> IMO, that would just encourage pile-on voting for free (and risk-free, since close votes can't be declined) flag weight.

Going in the direction that John suggested in his answer and somehow implementing a potential loss in flag weight is too complicated, as he insinuated.

I think the problem (if you want to regard it as one) is the Marshall badge itself. It just doesn't make sense on a small site. Particularly if it lacks bad posts to such a degree as tex.sx does – I'm glad I could contribute to the entertainment of the enviers `;-)`.

Answer (score 10):

If you have too much rep, offer some bounties till you drop below 3000.  Then you can dupe-flag again!

Comment: But what about [the highest rep user on TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer)? That would take him too long. We need bigger / instant award bounties!

Comment: Nice!  I've noticed that's your strategy here on MSO :)

Comment: @squillman Just till I get the Marshal badge :P

Answer (score 0):

I agree, but only if *unsuccessful* (expired?) close votes cause a *decrease* in flag weight.

Comment: Now that wouldn't help with the pile-on voting, plus it'd make people afraid of casting the first stone. I think the system is fine as it is.

Comment: @lunboks My point was that if we make this change, it would require many other changes to a system that works fine as is.