# Helpful flags not getting updated after getting 'close question' privilege

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, helpful-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increasing Flag Weight when you have Voting Privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96359/increasing-flag-weight-when-you-have-voting-privileges)

I recently got the ability to cast close votes. So, even if I flag a question as 'not constructive' or 'not a real question', it is still considered as a close vote. What is strange is that my 'helpful flag' count has stopped increasing after this change. Or at least it doesn't increase in cases where my flagging was automatically changed to a close vote and the post actually was closed. Is this how it is supposed to be?

I am guessing that once the post gets closed, the moderators are probably not bothered about marking flags as helpful. The only problem is that the Deputy badge will be much more difficult to get now. Earlier all the flags were getting converted to helpful, but now they just go in as close votes and don't show up on my profile page.

Comment: "the Deputy badge will be much more difficult to get now" I can assure you that even if that was true a year or two ago, it's not anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increasing Flag Weight when you have Voting Privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96359/increasing-flag-weight-when-you-have-voting-privileges) and [Why has my flag weight stopped at 300?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100312/why-has-my-flag-weight-stopped-at-300)

Answer (score 6):

> I am guessing that once the post gets closed, the moderators are probably not bothered about marking flags as helpful.

No, once you close 3k you close flags are automatically converted to close votes. You've been granted the privilege to close; make use of it.

> The only problem is that the Deputy badge will be much more difficult to get now.

No. Take a look at [review](/review). There you can:

- Check posts which are not answers.
- Review for spam posts.
- Check for posts that should be migrated to sites not on the current migration list.

And flag them appropriately.